# How to instantiate local variables in decision tables

Tags: drools

I am pretty new to drools and am given the below task.

I am inserting a few POJO into my KieSession object and am retreiving them into variables in my decision table as follows.

```
CONDITION            CONDITION            CONDITION          ACTION
abc: classABC       xyz: classXYZ        lmn : classLMN
var1 == $param       var2 == $param                                                                                

1                   2                     3
```

As far as I understand, the above table would yield the following rule

```
 when 
    abc:classABC(var1==1)
    xyz:classXYZ(var2==2)
    lmn:classLMN(var3==3)
 then
    some action
```

What I want is to get the following.

```
  when 
    abc:classABC(var1==1)
    xyz:classXYZ(var2==2)
    lmn:classLMN(var3==3)
    fgh:classFGH($var:var4)           // I think this step is creating a new variable to hold value of var4
 then
    some action
```

How do I get this on a decision table ?

I tried just adding a condition column with the variable declaration as fgh :classFGH, but since there is no data to be provided in the data row, this column would be ignored. If I do, give some data, there is an error at compile time "no code sinppet at xyz column". All I need is to declare a variable that can hold the value of the object that I have passed in my main method and use that object later in a different column of my decision table.

Comment: If you are assigning a variable to the POJO fact, by convention it is prefixed with `$`, viz `when $abc:classABC(var1==1)`

Comment: but thats just the naming convention right ? I mean it wouldnt really impact the functionality.

Comment: I think you need a global? But how can you "pass an object in [the] main method"?

Comment: I am inserting multiple objects into the KieSession. I am working on the generated HelloWorld program that eclipse generates when creating a new drools project.

Comment: If you are a beginner, I suggest you start by writing DRL rules by hand unless your logic is really and truly structured to fit the narrow design pattern of a decision table. As soon as you leave the run-of-the-mill pattern "snippet here, value below" things can get very nasty indeed.

Comment: At the moment, it looks to me as though the solution you are attempting does not fit with the problem you are trying to solve, so you really need to take a step back and work out what DRL would produce the correct pattern match. As @laune says, start with working DRL. Never build a decision table until you know exactly what DRL would make the correct pattern match. Once you know what DRL needs to be produced, it should be obvious whether a decision table is an effective way to generate it.

Comment: Well i did manage to get it working with the DRL, i was just hoping I could get it working with a spreadsheet decision table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the requirement around the decision table, but you can 'use' the firing of a rule to create new facts and insert them, with parameters from the original events. These can then be used to trigger further rules, like so (assuming `var4` is boolean):

```
declare AllMoonsInAlignmentEvent
    @role (event)
    extraCheese : boolean
end

rule "Some Rule"
  when
    $abc:classABC(var1==1)
    $xyz:classXYZ(var2==2)
    $lmn:classLMN(var3==3)
    $fgh:classFGH($var:var4)
 then
    ... some action using `$var`, `$abc` etc
    AllMoonsInAlignmentEvent myEvent= new AllMoonsInAlignmentEvent();
    myEvent.extraCheese = $var;
    insert(myEvent); 

rule "With Extra Cheese"
 when
    $moonsAligned:AllMoonsInAlignmentEvent(extraCheese == true)
 then
    ...

rule "Without Extra Cheese"
 when
    $moonsAligned:AllMoonsInAlignmentEvent(extraCheese == false)
 then
    ...
```

Comment: What I needed was, I already have an object of a certain class. I need to hold the value of an attribute of that object in a variable and use that variable across the rule, maybe even pass it into a function defined in my decision table(the decision table is created using xls).

Comment: Its kind of easy to declare that variable in a .drl file but getting the same functionality on a spreadsheet decision table is where I am stuck. For eg: My first when-then statement can be represented in a decision table using the (crude) table on the top. but how do i represent the second when-then statement in a decision table?

Answer (score 0):

You can get X($y:y) into a spreadsheet in two ways. First, in column 4

```
X($y:y /*$param*/)
```

and fill the column with any character you like. The other way might be in column 3 (!)

```
fgh:classFGH($var:var4) lmn:classLMN
var3==$param
```

These tricks are always a bit iffy. Rules requiring the simple "grab" of a fact aren't typical for spreadsheets and could be the first indication that you aren't pursuing the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

- CONDITION
- fgh:classFGH
- $param:var4
- Comment cell
- $var

Comment: Mind to add some explanation?